# Expanded option on 2nd column in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have created a RADGrid in my project and i want the Expanded option on the 2nd column instead of the default 1st. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Can you please write some code there so, we will understand what exactly you need to do and where we can change ?

Comment: you wont under stand the problem from code.
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/hierarchy-with-templates/defaultcs.aspx
i am making such a grid. but instead of expanding the grid at level of 1st column, i want an expansion at 2nd column.

Comment: I just posted another answer that achieves your functionality completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting another answer because it's quite different from what I had in my previous reply and putting both into one answer would be very confusing for the reader.

This solution achieves your requirement in a 100% manner as you can see in following screen shot. However, this is a highly customized solution and my previous reply is a good fit if you want to stick to only what's available out-of-the-box for RadGrid.

[image: EXpand Column shifted in Hierarchical grid]

Main points to keep in mind are as below.

- You need to have jquery included for this to work. You can easily do this by using the embedded jquery that comes with Telerik control library. I have mentioned the markup that will automatically include embedded jquery in your page.
- I have assumed that you are using server-side binding for hierarchical RadGrid.
- You need to simply add JavaScript block shown below to your aspx page for this to work.
- I am moving the expand column to just before the 3rd column, but you can move it to any position by setting the `newPosition` variable to an appropriate value.
- In your scenario, you would set newPosition to 1, so expand column appears just before the second column.
- Note that when then expand column is shifted, then it's also necessary to shift the header of expand column else the column headers will not be aligned with their columns.

*JavaScript for this solution*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        $ = $telerik.$;//make sure you can use $ symbol for embedded jquery
        var newPosition = 2;//set this to 1 or 2 or 3 etc.(but never 0) 
                            //depending on your requirement

        //gridClientId is  the server-side RadGrid1.ClientID property i.e. id of radgrid div element in rendered page
        //var gridClientId = "<%=RadGrid1.ClientId%>";
        var grid = $find(gridClientId);

        var dataItems = grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();

        for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {

           //get the expand column for the the row with index i
            var row = $(grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[i].get_element());
            var expandColumn = row.find("td.rgExpandCol");

            //move the data row expand column
            expandColumn.detach().insertBefore(row.find("td:eq(" + newPosition + ")"));
            expandColumn.width(50);
        }

        //move the column header for expand column
        var headerRow = $(grid.get_masterTableView().HeaderRow);
        var headerExpandColumn = headerRow.find(".rgExpandCol");
        headerExpandColumn.detach().insertBefore(headerRow.find("th:eq(" + newPosition+ ")"));
        headerExpandColumn.width(50);

    });

</script>
```

*Markup for including embedded jquery*

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
    <%!-- othert scripts of your page will go here -->
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

Comment: @Ajay, Please mark this as an answer if it satisfies your requirements. This is in the best interest of all involved.

Comment: is there a way i can handle this from CS code... for instance... i have an employee id in 1st column, when i click any particular employee id, the expand button should move to 2nd column and grid should contain all the employee reporting to its parent employee id(the one clicked earlier)

Comment: Its not possible from server side. I tried to do that first but it did not succeed. So, you want the expand button after employee id column, but on clicking anywhere in the employee row the row should expand. Is that what you want?

Comment: i have kept the employee button as link button. as soon as i click any employee link button, i want the expand option on 2nd column ...but initially the expand button should be on 1st column. is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the markup of your RadGrid including the link button? What you could do is add an asp:HiddenField to your page, whose value you set to 1 in code-behind when employeeid link button is clicked; then use the same Javascript code that I have mentioned in answer but only execute the script if hidden field value is 1. That should implement your scenario. Don't forget to set hidden field value to empty string just after Javascript code executes in document ready event.

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="rgvCampaign"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="False"
            AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="false" OnNeedDataSource="rgvCampaign_NeedDataSource"
            OnItemCommand="rgvCampaign_ItemCommand" OnPreRender="rgvCampaign_PreRender">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
            <MasterTableView AllowMultiColumnSorting="True"
                GroupLoadMode="Server" DataKeyNames="astellas_cmpgn_ID">
incontinuation...

Comment: <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCampaignIDColumn" runat="server" Text="Campaign ID"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCampaignID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("astellas_cmpgn_ID") %>' OnClick="lbtnCampaignID_Click">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>

Comment: So, just add C# code to `lbtnCampaignID_Click` event to set hidden field value to 1. Then follow the method I mentioned in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with RadGrid. The expand button is always going to be placed just before the first column in each row. However, with some templating as described below you can achieve this.

- If you wanted to expand on clicking the second column, then make the second column a GridTemplateColumn.
- The outer RadGrid should have only 2 columns with first columns being displayed like a regular column and second column being displayed as a collapsed RadGrid.
- In the template for this column, `place a RadGrid that has hierarchy
  enabled` and which binds to only the values for the row of first
  column.
- Then, you would end up with your requirement being implemented.

Note that you should bind the RadGrid in template column to same data source as the outer RadGrid in NeedDataSource event of RadGrid. The only difference would be the inner RdGrid would have hierarchy enabled and you would need to use appropriate events for implementing hierarchy for the inner RadGrid.

```
 protected void RadGrid2_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
 {
    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = GetDataTable();
 }
```

Comment: hi sunil,
can you please write the other answer again which you had written earlier as well.... it was helpful as well

Comment: I will post it in next couple of hours.